# How to remove one piece of a pelmet

Tags: kitchens

I need to remove the side portion of a pelmet above a kitchen cupboard.

The problem is that I cannot find how it is secured. It is fixed solidly, I cannot move it with moderate hand pressure.

[image: Sdde view]

The picture from inside the cabinet shows no screws into this piece. A screw is visible into the front pelmet, which should to be left in place. The dark spot midway along the side is a hole – I can insert a small screwdriver blade about 30mm into it.

[image: Inside]

I have tried from above. After scraping off years’ of grime, I cannot see or feel any screw heads.

Is it possible it is glued into place, or perhaps secured with dowels? Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

[image: Top]

My last resort is a big hammer, but I do not want to damage the cupboard or the front pelmet.

The reason I want to remove the side piece is to box-in the central heating boiler and hide the ugly filter and pipework above it.

Comment: pry bar, sawzall, or a new fancy oscillating cutter

Comment: Mine were screwed down from the top - is this a screw? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XewNW.png

Comment: [#til](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelmet) "Cabinet crown" is probably a more common and appropriate term. A pelmet usually conceals curtain hardware.

Comment: "What is a pelmet instead of a cornice? Cornice is the trim that sits at the top of the wall unit . Pelmet or light pelmet as some people call it, **is the trim that fits underneath your wall units**. Plinth is the skirting, the panel that fits around the bottom of your base units."

Comment: "What is the Difference Between Cornice and Crown Moulding ... They both serve as the “cap” or “crown” to a wall or cabinet and can be modern and simple or elaborate and decorative. However, **crown moulding is strictly an interior design element, unlike cornice, which we see in exterior and interior designs**. You may also see crown moulding used with cornice in interior design."

Comment: "What is a cabinet crown? ... Crown: /kroun/ noun: the top or highest part of something. verb: rest on or form the top of. In cabinet design, one of the most common details added is molding that is mounted to the top of wall and tall cabinets, hence why it is referred to as **crown molding**."

Comment: Just to clarify - you don't need to save this part; your prime motivation here is not damaging the cupboard or the front piece?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The side moldings are likely just glued to the front piece at the mitered joints, and only the front piece might be attached the cabinet (it doesn't need to bear much load). If so, it will be easier (and will cause less damage) to remove the entire assembly even though you don't actually need to remove the front or right side.

I would try unscrewing the screws on the underside of the top of the cabinet along the front edge, as these are probably what is holding the pelmet assembly on.

Comment: Pull the whole thing, +1.... and **that screw wouldn't belong there otherwise**, +2. And there's also ad-hock ones in the middles of the corners for the side strips.

Comment: You are right, the side piece was just glued. Removing the two front screws and lifting provided just enough clearance to insert a bolster chisel and prise off the side piece.

Answer (score 10):

I'd expect it's attached with **finishing nails**, having small heads that are driven below the surface with a nail-set and then the holes filled with wood filler or putty. As such, I'd expect to need to pry it off.

Comment: The miter joint may be glued. Time to gently but persistently hit it from behind with a hammer.

Comment: @Triplefault glued miters are such a pain. Hopefully they are just held together with some extra finishing nails driven perpendicular to each end.

Comment: No nails, just glue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Take down the whole cabinet, do the finishing, and hang it back?
Remember to mark the original cabinet height.
Mind that you will need couple milimeters of space above to hang it back - you can hide your boxing partially inside the top rim so the gap isn't visible.